# Twitter API (Tweepy) Get tweets from last 24 hours

Tags: python, api, twitter, tweepy

I have been searching for a solution but I haven't found none that could fix my problem, I am trying to collect tweets from a certain account but that are only 24 hours old or newer. What parameter should I add to api.user_timeline in order to only get results from the last 24 hours? I know you can specify since dates and stuff but I don't want dates, I really just want tweets from the last 24 hours and I'm not sure how to do it.

```
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline,
                   screen_name='###'
                   ).items(1):
                   try:
                       if not tweet.retweeted:
                               tweet.retweet()
                               print("###, Working...")
                               sleep(10)
```

Comment: As you "cursor" through tweets back in time, simply check each tweet's timestamp. Tweets will be chronologically ordered. When you encounter a timestamp that is more than 24 hours old, simply stop processing additional tweets.

Comment: and how would I put that into actual code?

Comment: A general outline would be the following. You would look up the Twitter doc for `statuses/user_timeline` [here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/timelines/api-reference/get-statuses-user_timeline.html) which will explain what gets returned, including the timestamp. Then you would lookup how to compare this timestamp with 24 hours in the past. If the comparison is older then you would use a `break` statement to bail out of the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

tweets_list = tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q=search_words + str(yesterday) + " until:" +str(today),tweet_mode='extended',lang='fa').items()

for tweet in tweets_list:
    if tweet.created_at>datetime.datetime.now()-timedelta(hours=24):
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit your answer with a minimal reproducible example, for example fix the imports, and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See How to Answer. 
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer